# Calculate the length of a polygon in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, geometry, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe:

```
    lon           lat         geometry
0   31.269899   30.072927   POINT (30.07293 31.26990)
1   31.269413   30.073965   POINT (30.07397 31.26941)
2   31.268751   30.073629   POINT (30.07363 31.26875)
3   31.269287   30.073505   POINT (30.07351 31.26929)
4   31.269081   30.074694   POINT (30.07469 31.26908)
```

I created a polygon out of all of those points like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df['lat'],df['lon']))
points = [x for x in gdf.geometry]
polygon = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in points])
print(polygon)
```

The output is a polygon:

```
POLYGON ((30.072927474975586 31.269899368286133, 30.073965072631836 31.269412994384766, 30.07362937927246 31.26875114440918, 30.073505401611328 31.269287109375, 30.07469367980957 31.269081115722656, 30.073972702026367 31.269569396972656, 30.074140548706055 31.269651412963867, 30.07431983947754 31.26882553100586,...)
```

How can I get the length in meters? to get the distance between the first retailer for example and the last retailer on the map, so that it takes a shape of a line that you can measure.

I tried this code:

```
polygon.length * 0.000621371
```

It gave : 5.04009394506436e-05

Which is wrong.

What am I doing wrong here guys?

Comment: Nice job to produce a good minimal reproducible example! +1

Comment: yeah whatever you say

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is using `geopy` and it's function called `distance`, adding some changes to your code. [geopy distance documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance)

Usage:

```
geopy.distance.distance([from.lon, from.lat], [to.lon, to.lat]).km
```

Not sure if there's a built-in function to convert to meters, but having kilometers it should be easy to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the length in meters?

The unit distance between coordinates (lat, lon) is kilometers so to convert in meters just multiply by 1000:

```
>>> polygon.length * 1000
5.592554141703987  # meters
```

> polygon.length * 0.000621371

Do you want the distance in meters or miles?

Comment: how about the area?

Comment: because the length of the polygon is no way = 82 meters!

Comment: For your sample 82meters?

Comment: The sample I provided is very small because the data is confidential.

Comment: It's for the whole sample I have in my laptop

Comment: Did you try to multiply by 1000 your whole sample?

Comment: yes I did, Indeed

Comment: @Corralien are you suggesting that degrees of lat/lon are the same as kilometers?? Maybe I’m misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem why you're not getting a valid measure is that you're dealing with a [`shapely.Polygon`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.Polygon.html#shapely.Polygon) object. In fact, since this one (as far as I know) does not have a notion of **(CRS)**, you need at first convert each point/xy of your polygon to a projected system that uses meters (i.e, [*EPSG 32636*](https://epsg.io/32636)) before calculating its length.

To achieve this, you can use [`pyproj.transformer.Transformer`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer) :

```
from pyproj import Transformer #pip install pyproj
​
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", "epsg:32636", always_xy=True)

x, y = zip(*polygon.exterior.coords)
x, y = transformer.transform(x, y)

polygon_v2 = Polygon(zip(x, y))
L = polygon_v2.length
```

Output :

```
print(L)
​#560.2377719253593
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin with a function that computes geodesic distance in km.

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

def dkm(frLat, frLon, toLat, toLon):
    """
    Compute geodesic length in kilometers
    Lat, long of point1: frLat, frLon
    Lat, long of point2: toLat, toLon
    """
    #print("frLon,frLat,toLon,toLat:", frLon, "|", frLat, "|", toLon, "|", toLat)
    dist = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(frLat, frLon, toLat, toLon)
    return dist["s12"] / 1000
```

Continue working from `polygon` object, the working code:

```
# ...
segleng = [0]
eaold = []
for ix,ea in enumerate(polygon.exterior.coords):
    if ix>0:
        frLat, frLon = eaold
        toLat, toLon = ea
        gccdist_km = dkm(frLat, frLon, toLat, toLon)
        segleng.append(gccdist_km)
        print(f"Segment:{ix:3.0f}   Length_km:{gccdist_km:9.4f}   Cumulative_dist:{sum(segleng):9.4f}")
    eaold = ea
```

```
Segment:  1   Length_km:   0.1242   Cumulative_dist:   0.1242
Segment:  2   Length_km:   0.0739   Cumulative_dist:   0.1981
Segment:  3   Length_km:   0.0535   Cumulative_dist:   0.2516
Segment:  4   Length_km:   0.1333   Cumulative_dist:   0.3849
Segment:  5   Length_km:   0.2112   Cumulative_dist:   0.5961
```

Conclusion:

```
# Sum of segment distances in meters
print(f"Total distance: {sum(segleng)*1000:9.3f} meters")
```

```
Total distance:  596.069 meters
```